# Selectize dropdown content not rendered on page load in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).

On page load when inspecting the elements in Selectized drop-down the the actual content is missing (inside `.selectize-dropdown-content`):

```
<div class="selectize-dropdown single aritklmodel" style="display: none;">
  <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
</div>
```

After the click it populates the content:

```
<div class="selectize-dropdown single aritklmodel" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 255.617px; top: 34px; left: 0px;">
  <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
    <div style="display: block" data-marka="2" data-selectable="" data-value="a2" class="">a2</div>
    <div style="display: block" data-marka="1" data-selectable="" data-value="A50">A50</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to populate it on page load?

Because as seen from above I use custom data attributes with whom I filter the options based on previous Selectized drop-down selection.

Current problem is that when i make selection in first drop-down the filter is not working as it has nothing to filter, as content is not in DOM, just after i click once on second drop-down and content populates in DOM the filtering starts working after changes on first one.

I tried triggering/simulating the click event, its not working.

I have read API and usage documentation, if I missed answer, I didn't understand it (not a native english speaker)

```js
$('select').selectize({

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Is there a way to programmatically de-selectize the HTML select, so I can do filtering on HTML select itself, and then selectize it again?

Is there any way of doing filtering of one selectized drop-down based on another? Using data attribute or any other?

Comment: can you create working code ?

Comment: @Swati I tried searching for CDN or other source to include selectize in fiddle, cant find it...

Comment: You can find [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/selectize.js) and [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) as well

Comment: @Swati I have added fiddle. On load there are no options inside `selectize-dropdown-content`

Comment: This is default behaviour as i can see not sure if there is any alternative if i found i will let you know .

Comment: @Swati Thanks for your time. I asked on github as well.

Comment: Can you simply clone the `<select>` prior initializing `Selectize` and do filtering on the clone? I think you then could be able to (re)initialize `Selectize` with newly filtered options. Alternatively, could you simply filter a data structure in the code, and then build a DOM from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `refreshOptions` method to `populate` options on page load

Example 1

```js
// initialize the Selectize control
var $select = $('select').selectize({});

// fetch the instance
var selectize = $select[0].selectize; // 0 for select index
selectize.refreshOptions(false); // populate option on load
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Example 2

```js
// initialize the Selectize control
var $select = $('select').selectize({
    render: {
        option: function(data, escape) {
            return "<div class='option selected' data-id='" + escape(data.id) + "'>" + escape(data.text) + "</div>"
        }
    }
});

// fetch the instance
let car_select = $select[0].selectize; // 0 index for car select
let model_select = $select[1].selectize; // 1 index for model select
model_select.refreshOptions(false); // populate model select options on page load
car_select.on('item_add', function(value, item) {
   let selector = model_select['$dropdown_content'].children();
   model_select.setValue('none');
   selector.hide();
   selector.each(function() {
       let tmp = $(this);
       if (tmp.data('id') == value) {
           tmp.show();
       }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option data-id="volvo" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option data-id="saab" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option data-id="mercedes" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option data-id="audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select name="models" id="models">
  <option data-data='{"id":"none"}' value="none">--Select model --</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"volvo"}' value="volvo xc90">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"volvo"}' value="volvo xc60">Volvo XC60</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"saab"}' value="saab 900 convertible">Saab 900 Convertible</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"mercedes"}' value="mercedes benz C class">Mercedes Benz C Class</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"mercedes"}' value="mercedes benz A class">Mercedes Benz A Class</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"audi"}' value="audi e-tron">Audi E-Tron</option>
  <option data-data='{"id":"audi"}' value="audi a7">Audi A7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `refreshOptions` was the thing I was missing, thanks.

Comment: @ikiK thanks and sorry i made typo of `refreshItems` in my post

Answer (score 1):

*This is alternative solution*.

Whenever your `selectize-input` is clicked you can checked if the input where click event has taken place is related to which select depending on this perform tasks .If its for `something`(just for example) then you first need to hide all divs inside `selectize-dropdown-content` and then check if data-attribute matches with the value of `cars` select-box depending on this show that div else hide.Also, as divs are generated on click of input-box so you can make one option selected as default .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('select#cars').selectize();
$('select#something').selectize({
  render: {
    option: function(data, escape) {
      return "<div class='option selected' data-marka='" + escape(data.marka) + "'>" + escape(data.text) + "</div>"
    }
  }
});

$(".selectize-input").on('click', function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest(".outer").find(".selectize-dropdown-content div")
  //get value of other select
  var value = $("#cars").val()
  //check if id is something
  if ($(this).closest(".outer").find('select').attr('id') == "something") {
    selector.hide() //hide divs
    selector.each(function() {
      //see if data-marka match value
      if ($(this).data('marka') === value || $(this).data('value') == 'none') {
        $(this).show() //show that div
      }
    })
  } else {
    //if cars select box is change find next select-box input and change it to default
    $(this).closest(".outer").next().find(".selectize-control .item").attr('data-value', "none")
    $(this).closest(".outer").next().find(".selectize-control .item").text("--Select one --");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <select id="something">
    <option value="none">--Select one --</option>
    <option data-data='{"marka": "volvo"}' value="1">1</option>
    <option data-data='{"marka": "volvo"}' value="2">2</option>
    <option data-data='{"marka": "Saab"}' value="3">3</option>
    <option data-data='{"marka": "audi"}' value="4">4</option>
    <option data-data='{"marka": "mercedes"}' value="5">5</option>
    <option data-data='{"marka": "mercedes"}' value="6">6</option>
  </select>
  <div>
```

Comment: Creative, the idea of filtering after click on second drop-down  based on selected first drop-down somehow skipped my mind. Thanks.